# How to send and receive data on http/https port in c++?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, websocket, port

I want to make a server in C++ that can use HTTP/HTTPS port to send and receive data.

I have tried a simple TCP Server in C++ that can listen on various ports to send and receive data. But I want to use port 80 or 443 for listening and communication. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Sure, those ports are only assigned to http/https by convention. If they're not already being used by something else you should be able to use them from anything you want. Is there some underlying agenda here about trying to appear as though you are an http server even though you're not?

Comment: How much data? What kind of data? Did you encounter some particular problem? What libraries did you try? What information have you found so far? Go into (much) more detail.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError They're usually reserved to privileged processes if under 1024, at least on POSIXy systems

Comment: Also if you want to implement HTTP, you should use an actual HTTP library. Don't try to implement it yourself. There's no point and you will get it wrong.

Comment: [POCO](https://pocoproject.org) library can be used to make a C++ server. please take look at this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252827/Learning-Poco-A-Simple-HTTP-Server)

Comment: [httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) is much easier to use and lightweight than most other libraries.

Comment: @nada - unless you're implementing a toy / small project, avoid `httplib` - it uses a [thread-per-client model](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/7231f6fe0070d70ef3115bdc0aa3df186be0d626/httplib.h#L1941-L1954), which is suboptimal for higher loads.

Comment: @Myst Exactly, but also don't take a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library does not have an API for HTTP. You can find the HTTP specification here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 Also pay attention to the "obsoleted" and "updated by" links, which lead you to specs that will also be important to implementing a HTTP server or client, for example for implementing HTTPS.

The C++ standard does not have an API for TCP, IP, or any other form of network communication either (although a networking Technical Specification has been proposed, and may be introduced into C++23 or later standard). You can find IP spec here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791 and TCP spec here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793. That said, if you are targeting an operating system, then it probably provides an API for TCP, and you don't need to implement it yourself. First step in using the API provided by your operating system is to figure out what operating system you are targeting.

> I want to use port 80 or 443 for listening and communication

You can do that. As long as there is no other process listening on those ports, and as long as your process has sufficient privileges, then this should be possible. See documentation of your operating system for more details.